# A very simple program based on YOUTUBE-DL

Tags: python

I've written a personal simple program that extracts links from a website and downloads the links via `youtube-dl` but I have a problem with the download part because it stops downloading after finishing the first video for example and the problem is with the `Downloader` function. The website I'm trying to download from is `https://maktabkhooneh.org/` in case you want to test it and in the code, I've commented a URL of a course that you can you use it.

here is what I've done so far:

```
import requests
import subprocess
import getpass
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
# import argparse # Add Command Line Arguments to a Python Script (switch_flag)


def Login(url, login_route, username, password):

    headers = {
        'User-Agent': '',
        'origin': url,
        'referer': url + login_route,
    }

    request_session = requests.session()

    csrf_token = request_session.get(url).cookies['csrftoken']

    login_payload = {
        'hidden_username': username,
        'password': password,
        'csrfmiddlewaretoken': csrf_token
    }

    login_request = request_session.post(
        url + login_route, headers=headers, data=login_payload)

    if login_request.status_code == 200:
        msg = f'\nYou have logged in successfully {login_request.status_code}'
    else:
        msg = f'\nError {login_request.status_code}'

    print(msg)


def get_user_input():

    url = input('URL: ')
    username = getpass.getpass('USERNAME: ')
    password = getpass.getpass('PASSWORD: ')
    login_route = input('LOGIN_ROUTE: ')

    return Login(url, login_route, username, password)


def Scraper(page_url):

    headers = {
        'User-Agent': ''
    }

    page = requests.get(
        page_url,
        headers=headers,
    )
    soup = bs(page.text, "html.parser")

    URL_List = []
    link_count = 0
    for a_tag in soup.select('a[href^="/course/"]'):

        links = "https://maktabkhooneh.org" + a_tag["href"]

        URL_List.append(links)
        link_count += 1

    return URL_List


def Donwloader(url_list):

    URL_List = Scraper(url_list)
    download_count = 0
    
    try:
        for links in URL_List:
            command = f'youtube-dl -o "D:/DW/%(title)s" {links}'
            result = subprocess.call(command, shell=True)

            if result == 0:
                download_count += 1

                return('\nReturned Value', result)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        
        print('Paused ;)')
            

    return f'\n{download_count} file(s) have been downloaded'




# Sample: https://maktabkhooneh.org/course/%D8%A2%D9%85%D9%88%D8%B2%D8%B4-%D8%B1%D8%A7%DB%8C%DA%AF%D8%A7%D9%86-%DB%8C%D8%A7%D8%AF%DA%AF%DB%8C%D8%B1%DB%8C-%D9%85%D8%A7%D8%B4%DB%8C%D9%86-Andrew-NG-mk1085/%D9%81%D8%B5%D9%84-%D8%A7%D9%88%D9%84-%D9%85%D9%82%D8%AF%D9%85%D9%87-ch3364/%D9%88%DB%8C%D8%AF%DB%8C%D9%88-%D8%AE%D9%88%D8%B4%D8%A2%D9%85%D8%AF%DB%8C%D8%AF-%DB%8C%D8%A7%D8%AF%DA%AF%DB%8C%D8%B1%DB%8C-%D9%85%D8%A7%D8%B4%DB%8C%D9%86/

page_url = input('Please enter the page URL: ')

Login_permission = input('Login required Website [Y], [N]? ')
if Login_permission == 'y' or Login_permission == 'Y':
    get_user_input()

list_len = len(Scraper(page_url))
Download_Permission = input(
    f'\n{list_len} link(s) have been extracted. Do you want to DOWNLOAD them [Y], [N]? ')

Scraper(page_url)

if Download_Permission == 'y' or Download_Permission == 'Y':
    Donwloader(page_url)
else:
    print('\nProcess has been canceled ;)')
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        if result == 0:
            download_count += 1

            return('\nReturned Value', result)
```

If you return, you leave the function. You don't want that here.